# Error installing Rails 2.3 RC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to install rails using the following command:

```
$ sudo gem install rails --source http://gems.rubyonrails.org
```

But this is what i'm getting:

```
WARNING:  RubyGems 1.2+ index not found for:
        http://gems.rubyonrails.org/

RubyGems will revert to legacy indexes degrading performance.
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Package::FormatError)
    No metadata found!
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: what do you get when you run this with verbose output level? 
sudo gem install rails --source http://gems.rubyonrails.org -V

Answer (score 1):

Do you have at least gem version 1.3.1? It's required for Rails 2.2+.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the command it just tries to reinstall 2.3.1. I was trying to upgrade yesterday ;)

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with your current sources. First, check the list of source by doing:

```
$ gem env | grep \"sources\"
```

Then, remove any non-standard repository:

```
$ sudo gem sources -r http://my_nonstandard_source.com
```

Then try to install it again:

```
$ sudo gem install rails --source http://gems.rubyonrails.org
```

Hopefully that'll be enough.